# Sum all columns with a wildcard name search using Python Pandas

Tags: python, wildcard, pandas

I have a dataframe in python pandas with several columns taken from a CSV file.

For instance, data =:

```
Day P1S1 P1S2 P1S3 P2S1 P2S2 P2S3
1   1    2    2    3    1    2
2   2    2    3    5    4    2
```

And what I need is to get the sum of all columns which name starts with P1... something like P1* with a wildcard.

Something like the following which gives an error:

> P1Sum = data["P1*"]

Is there any why to do this with pandas?

Comment: Is there any reason that people downvote this question?

Comment: I'm also not getting it. I mean, it can be a really basic thing, but I searched the documentation of Pandas and didn't find any answers.

Comment: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/dev/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html?highlight=filter#pandas.DataFrame.filter

Comment: Thank you, but that was not trivial. The documentation doesn't say anything on how to use the function, just says there is a function.
Anyway I found the answer and I will post it below.

Answer (score 65, accepted):

I found the answer.

Using the data, dataframe from the question:

```
from pandas import *

P1Channels = data.filter(regex="P1")
P1Sum = P1Channels.sum(axis=1)
```

Answer (score 6):

List comprehensions on columns allow more filters in the `if` condition:

```
In [1]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.arange(15).reshape(5, 3), columns=['P1S1', 'P1S2', 'P2S1'])

In [2]: df
Out[2]: 
   P1S1  P1S2  P2S1
0     0     1     2
1     3     4     5
2     6     7     8
3     9    10    11
4    12    13    14

In [3]: df.loc[:, [x for x in df.columns if x.startswith('P1')]].sum(axis=1)
Out[3]: 
0     1
1     7
2    13
3    19
4    25
dtype: int64
```

Comment: I find using `fnmatch` in the standard lib gives a lot of power in these "if" list comprehensions.

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for the tip jbssm, for anyone else looking for a sum total, I ended up adding `.sum()` at the end, so:

```
P1Sum= P1Channels.sum(axis=1).sum()
```